# Which IDE do the config file(package.des and xxx.prj ) belong to?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

which IDE do  the config file(package.des and xxx.prj ) belong to?

filename is xxx.prj and package.des

the content of package.des:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312"?>
<proje target="market" targettype="exe" hasdebug="yes" hasmap="no" hasprofile="no" multithread="yes" warninglevel="2" workdir="." libs="" cppflags="-g -ggdb3 -fpermissive" ldflags="" arflags="">
    <package name="utils" dir="../../src/base/utils"/>
    <package name="ini" dir="../../src/base/ini"/>
    <package name="json" dir="../../src/base/json"/>
    <package name="redis" dir="../../src/base/redis"/>
    <package name="printfc" dir="../../src/base/printfc"/>
    <package name="thread" dir="../../src/base/thread"/>
    <package name="baseexchapi" dir="../../src/business/engine"/>
    <package name="Thostlink" dir="../../src/business/ctp"/>
    <package name="linkmanager" dir="../../src/business/linkmanager"/>
    <package name="market" dir="../../src/business/market"/>
</project>
```

the content of xxx.prj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312"?>
<packageDefine name="utils" version="1" type="cpp" includedir="." platform="all">
    <parameter/>
    <depend>
        <package name="ini" version="1"/>
        <package name="printfc" version="1"/>
    </depend>
    <cppfile>
        <file name="Lib.cpp"/>
        <file name="Logger.cpp"/>       
    </cppfile>
    <headfile>
        <file name="Lib.h"/>
        <file name="Logger.h"/>     
        <file name="global.h"/>
    </headfile> 
    <command/>
</packageDefine>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6xUG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2b2u.png)

Comment: What's the specific problem you are trying to solve? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Google (or any other search engine is your friend), .des files are associated with Pro/DESKTOP (a CAD tool) and .prj seems to be related to AIMMS (another modelling tool)